# How to use an XML file from another computer?

Tags: linux, windows, network-shares, webserver, xml

I have a home management server (consisting of a Raspberry Pi with simple web server) on which I would like to have hard disk temperatures from computers in my home network. The other machines are windows based. They all run Sentinel HD for monitoring hd temperatures. Sentinel HD has a xml file in installation folder that can be used by the integrated web server to serve a static site with data about all the hard drives on that system. This solution does not help me, on one hand I need to open a page for each computer to see the data, on other the data served is to extensive.

One option that comes to my mind is to create a folder on each machine, to add a symbolic link of the xml file to that folder, to share the folder, to create (on Raspberry) a network drive for each of those computers and to create another symlink for xml files from network drives to the web server folder (/var/www). That should work, but I would like some simpler solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a better solution for my problem by looking at the problem from another perspective. I have created a small web server, which serves a static page (based on the xml file in question) from each of the computers in the network, on a specific port. Then I have created a simple php listener function on the Raspberry that parses relevant data from each of the sources and packs it to a multidimensional array for further use.